# POSTGRESQL-Converting multiple rows with different values to columns to one row and different columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

Hi Being new to POSTGRESQL, I need to convert the multiple rows of data to one row and several columns. How to do it in POSTGRESQL.
I want to convert the below data

[image]

Comment: Did you attach an image? If so it is not displaying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`bool_or()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) aggregate function to achieve this:

```
select movie, 
       bool_or(genre = 'Action') as  is_action,
       bool_or(genre = 'Fantasy') as  is_fantasy,
       bool_or(genre = 'Crime') as  is_crime,
       bool_or(genre = 'Comedy') as  is_comedy
from the_table       
group by movie
```

Note that this returns a real `boolean` value rather than `0` or `1` which I find much more logical for such a "flag" column. If you do prefer integers over boolean for a true/false flag, just cast the function's result to int, e.g. `bool_or(....)::int`

Comment: nice. I wasn't aware of that function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brute force way to do it. It could get tedious if you have a lot of genres.

First create tables and insert data. I created another movie for illustrative purposes:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (movie text, genre text);

INSERT INTO t1 (movie, genre)
     VALUES ('ABC', 'Action'),
            ('ABC', 'Fantasy'),
            ('DEF', 'Comedy'),
            ('DEF', 'Action');
```

To get the columns you want, first you can just create one row per movie per genre:

```
SELECT movie,
  CASE WHEN genre = 'Action' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isAction,
  CASE WHEN genre = 'Fantasy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isFantasy,  
  CASE WHEN genre = 'Comedy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isComedy,  
  CASE WHEN genre = 'Crime' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isCrime
 FROM t1
```

which gives too many rows

| movie | isaction | isfantasy | iscomedy | iscrime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ABC | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| DEF | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| DEF | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

But we can reduce the number of rows by doing a sum and GROUP BY genre

```
WITH t2 as (
SELECT movie,
  CASE WHEN genre = 'Action' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isAction,
  CASE WHEN genre = 'Fantasy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isFantasy,  
  CASE WHEN genre = 'Comedy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isComedy,  
  CASE WHEN genre = 'Crime' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isCrime
 FROM t1)
 
 SELECT movie, sum(isAction) as isAction,
               sum(isFantasy) as isFantasy, 
               sum(isComedy) as isComedy, 
               sum(isCrime) as isCrime
  FROM t2
  GROUP BY movie
```

which gives

| movie | isaction | isfantasy | iscomedy | iscrime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| DEF | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Now for some discussion on data types and getting this data into a table. As written these queries will have isAction, etc. columns as bigint. You might actually want boolean, in which case you have to cast first to int and then to boolean (e.g. `sum(isAction)::int::bool as isAction...`).

To get the data into a table replace the last SELECT query with a [SELECT INTO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html) query which will automatically create a new table for you.